# Running one specific <script> (Dreamweaver)

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver (CC 2015) to make a website for school and I am using JavaScript in the  tags to change the colour of text when you click on another body of text. I want it so only one specific script runs to change only that one body of text but, as it runs sequentially, it only changes the very last one, no matter which one I click on. The code that I am using is down below.

```
<script>
function changeColor(NES)

{document.getElementById('NES').style.color = "rgba(229,6,10,1.00)"; }

</script>

<script>
function changeColor(SES)

{document.getElementById('SES').style.color = "rgba(229,6,10,1.00)";}

</script>

<script>
function changeColor(GB)

{document.getElementById('GB').style.color = "rgba(229,6,10,1.00)";}

</script>
```

As well as,

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeColor(NES); return false;">NES</a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor(SES); return false;">Super NES </a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor(GB); return false;">Game Boy</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function changeColor(div)
{
    div.style.color = "rgba(229,6,10,1.00)"; 
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor(this);">NES</a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor(this);">Super NES </a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor(this);">Game Boy</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to change the colour of what I am clicking on, I want to change the colour of something else when I click on it, hence the getting elements by id.

Comment: <script>
    function changeColor(div){
 if(div=='NES'){
  document.getElementById(div).style.color =     "rgba(229,6,10,1.00)";
 }
 if(div=='NES1'){
  document.getElementById(div).style.color = "rgba(127,7,6,1.00)";
 }
 if(div=='NES2'){
  document.getElementById(div).style.color = "rgba(240,8,0,1.00)";
 }
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeColor('NES');" id="NES">NES</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeColor('NES1');" id="NES1">Super NES </a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeColor('NES2');" id="NES2">Game Boy</a>

Comment: Also is there a way that i can do this with a specific class?